# How can I make the header stick throughout the Page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the header `stick` on the top, throughout the page. And It works fine till `class="section"` but the PROBLEM is after first section the `header` element become hidden.

I have included some part of the code hope it'll help you understand my problem.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
    --primary-color: #b90415;
    --primary-color-hover: #d3071b;
    --secondary-color: #103063;
    --secondary-color-hover: #143f85;
    --light-color: #f4f4f4;
    --spotify-green:rgba(30, 215, 96,0.9);
}

html,body{
    font-family: 'Nunito',sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1.9em;
    color: var(--light-color);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
/*For all Links*/
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffffaf;
}
/*For all unorder-List*/
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*=====================Top navigation-bar style=====================*/
body div{
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
header{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #252529;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #00000055;
    z-index: 3;
}
.icon2{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
span, .icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon:hover{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#top-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
}
#top-nav ul li{
    float: left;
}
#top-nav ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 650;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#top-nav ul li a:hover:not(.icon){
    background-color: var(--spotify-green);
    color: #000;
}
/*=======================section style=======================*/
.section{
    background-image: linear-gradient(230deg,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0,0,0, 0.8)),url('img1.jpg');/* linear-gradient(230deg,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0,0,0, 0.8)),url('testimg.jpg');*/
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:x-large;
    padding: 180px 0;
}
.section p{
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 74%;
}
/*================================================================*/
.product-descr{
    background-color: #252529;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: larger;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.product-descr p{
    margin: 50px auto 15px auto;
    width: 74%;
}
.btn{
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(30, 215, 96,0.3);;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: large;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: var(--spotify-green);
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
img{
    width: 53%;
    margin: 28px auto;
}
/*=============================================================*/
/*section 3 style*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-IND">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&family=Inter:wght@300&family=Nunito:wght@300&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="top-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="icon" href="index.html"><span class="material-icons">home</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="mytunes.html">MyTunes</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#b1">Overview</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#b2">Music</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#b3">Video</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#b4">Gift Cards</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="icon2"><a class="icon" href="#"><span class="material-icons">menu</span></a></li></ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="section">
        <h1>Let it <span>Rythm</span></h1>
        <h3>Your music, movies, and TV shows take center stage.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, assumenda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="b1" class="section2 product-descr">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <h2>Music</h2>
        <h2>45 Million songs. Zero Ads</h2>
        <p>Stream over 45 million songs, ad-free. Or download albums and tracks to listen to offline. All the music in your personal Rythm library — no matter where it came from — lives right alongside the Rythm Music catalog. Start your free three-month trial with no commitment, and cancel anytime.</p>
        <div class="btn">Start Free Trial Now</div>
        <caption>Rythm Music is available in myTunes, and for iOS and Android devices.</caption>
        <img src="mockup1.png" alt="" width="750">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header should be `position:fixed` instead of `position: sticky`

```
header{
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; /*set width 100% for the entire header*/
    background-color: #252529;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #00000055;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
    --primary-color: #b90415;
    --primary-color-hover: #d3071b;
    --secondary-color: #103063;
    --secondary-color-hover: #143f85;
    --light-color: #f4f4f4;
    --spotify-green:rgba(30, 215, 96,0.9);
}

html,body{
    font-family: 'Nunito',sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 1.9em;
    color: var(--light-color);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
/*For all Links*/
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffffaf;
}
/*For all unorder-List*/
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*=====================Top navigation-bar style=====================*/
body div{
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #252529;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #00000055;
    z-index: 3;
}
.icon2{
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
span, .icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon:hover{
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#top-nav ul{
    margin: 0;
}
#top-nav ul li{
    float: left;
}
#top-nav ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 650;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
#top-nav ul li a:hover:not(.icon){
    background-color: var(--spotify-green);
    color: #000;
}
/*=======================section style=======================*/
.section{
    background-image: linear-gradient(230deg,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0,0,0, 0.8)),url('img1.jpg');/* linear-gradient(230deg,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),rgba(0,0,0, 0.8)),url('testimg.jpg');*/
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:x-large;
    padding: 180px 0;
}
.section p{
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 74%;
}
/*================================================================*/
.product-descr{
    background-color: #252529;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: larger;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.product-descr p{
    margin: 50px auto 15px auto;
    width: 74%;
}
.btn{
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(30, 215, 96,0.3);;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: large;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: var(--spotify-green);
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
img{
    width: 53%;
    margin: 28px auto;
}
/*=============================================================*/
/*section 3 style*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-IND">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&family=Inter:wght@300&family=Nunito:wght@300&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="top-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="icon" href="index.html"><span class="material-icons">home</span></a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="mytunes.html">MyTunes</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#b1">Overview</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#b2">Music</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#b3">Video</a></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#b4">Gift Cards</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="icon2"><a class="icon" href="#"><span class="material-icons">menu</span></a></li></ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="section">
        <h1>Let it <span>Rythm</span></h1>
        <h3>Your music, movies, and TV shows take center stage.</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, assumenda.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, assumenda.</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="b1" class="section2 product-descr">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <h2>Music</h2>
        <h2>45 Million songs. Zero Ads</h2>
        <p>Stream over 45 million songs, ad-free. Or download albums and tracks to listen to offline. All the music in your personal Rythm library — no matter where it came from — lives right alongside the Rythm Music catalog. Start your free three-month trial with no commitment, and cancel anytime.</p>
        <div class="btn">Start Free Trial Now</div>
        <caption>Rythm Music is available in myTunes, and for iOS and Android devices.</caption>
        <img src="mockup1.png" alt="" width="750">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok It works...But why `position: sticky;`  doesn't work? It should stick at the top while scrolling right? In last project it was working just fine

Comment: this document (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-positionsticky-and-positionfixed-in-css/#:~:text=Element%20with%20position%3A%20fixed%20property,2.) has full explanation for you. Here is the reason for your case `sticky property leaves the viewport when its parent element scrolls off the viewport.`